# Apply twitter bootstrap collapse plugin on a plain ul list

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla3.0

I have this html markup generated by Joomla 3.1 by creating a menu:

```
<ul class="nav menu">
    <li class="item-106 first deeper parent">
        <a href=""><span>MENU 1</span></a>
        <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
            <li>
                <a href=""><span>SUB-MENU 1</span></a>
                <a href=""><span>SUB-MENU 2</span></a>
                <a href=""><span>SUB-MENU 3</span></a>
            </li> 
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-111 first deeper parent">
        <a href=""><span>MENU 2</span></a>
        <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
            <li>
                <a href=""><span>SUB-MENU 4</span></a>
                <a href=""><span>SUB-MENU 5</span></a>
                <a href=""><span>SUB-MENU 6</span></a>
            </li> 
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

1. Is it possible to apply a bootstrap collapsible group menu on it, without adding extra classes/attributes like:

   class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne"...
2. If the answer is no on question 1: how can I add these extra stuff on the generated html markup

Thanks for your help.